# How can I handle this cast exception in C# : system.data.model in system.windows.controls.CheckBox?

Tags: c#, checkbox, casting, system.data

This is my model class of analys

```
public partial class analys
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public bool Type_qualitatif { get; set; }
        public bool Type_quantitatif { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime create_at { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime update_at { get; set; }
        public int sectionId { get; set; }
    
        public virtual section section { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I create a ListBox which display checkboxes as items, and the content of each one is the name of an analys.

So I am trying to get the content of the checkboxes checked and save them in a list with the code bellow

```
foreach ( CheckBox item in  _biochimieExam.BiochimieExamsItemsControl.Items )
             {
                 if(item.IsChecked == true)
                 {
                   //  String exam = item.Content.ToString();
                     SelctedItems.Add(item.Content.ToString());
                 }
             } 
            
            foreach(String item in SelctedItems)
            {
                BchExamsList.Add(new analys
                {
                    name = item
                }) ;
            }
```

But I'm getting an inavlid cast exception **Impossible to cast an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.analys_F69488E20B133B223573E1D5931B83214F85574493596933EB8BFDBD5F513C59' in type 'System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox'.'** which I try to resolve. But a I failed.

Please I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve the problem by using the CheckListBox of  Xceed toolkit package.

My objective was to get the value of checked checkBoxes. In first I was using a ListBox with CheckBoxes as it's items. And that is why I write this code

```
foreach ( CheckBox item in  _biochimieExam.BiochimieExamsItemsControl.Items )
             {
                 if(item.IsChecked == true)
                 {
                   //  String exam = item.Content.ToString();
                     SelctedItems.Add(item.Content.ToString());
                 }
             } 
            
            foreach(String item in SelctedItems)
            {
                BchExamsList.Add(new analys
                {
                    name = item
                }) ;
            }
```

To resolve my problem I make these changes in my code :

the Xaml

```
 <XceedToolkit:CheckListBox Margin="5,5" x:Name="BiochimieExamsItemsControlXceed" 
                                   ValueMemberPath="name"  DisplayMemberPath="name" FontWeight="Bold"
                                   SelectedMemberPath="name" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"  
                                   SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedItems}"
                                   Style="{DynamicResource ListAnalysesItemsControlXceed}" ItemSelectionChanged="BiochimieExamsItemsControlXceed_ItemSelectionChanged" >

            <XceedToolkit:CheckListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="white"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="white"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="16"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,2"/>
                    
                    
                 
              
                </Style>
            </XceedToolkit:CheckListBox.Resources>
            
        </XceedToolkit:CheckListBox>
```

And in the code behind :

```
public ObservableCollection<Object> BchSelectedExams { get; set; }


        public void BiochimieExamsItemsControlXceed_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.ItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            BchSelectedExams = (ObservableCollection<object>)BiochimieExamsItemsControlXceed.SelectedItems;
           

            foreach (analys o in BiochimieExamsItemsControlXceed.SelectedItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o.name);
              
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
foreach ( CheckBox item in _biochimieExam.BiochimieExamsItemsControl.Items )
```

you are trying to treat every element in `_biochimieExam.BiochimieExamsItemsControl.Items` as a Checkbox, but elements in `_biochimieExam.BiochimieExamsItemsControl.Items` ar of type `analys`.

try this instead:

```
foreach (analys item in _biochimieExam.BiochimieExamsItemsControl.CheckedItems)
{
    BchExamsList.Add(new analys
    {
        name = item.name
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the ListBox don't have a method to track the checkBoxes checked. So there is an error with the code  _biochimieExam.BiochimieExamsItemsControl.CheckedItems

Comment: Is there any itemsControl which can track the checked CheckBoxes as it's items ?

Comment: I forgot to mention in my answer that you should actually use a CheckedListBox, another standard control that has same functionalities of ListBox, plus checkboxes.